# Object has type qualifiers that prevent match (function overload not found)

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I have a simple class, intended to convert integers to byte arrays.

```
class mc_int {
    private: 
        int val;      //actual int
    public: 
        int value();  //Returns value
        int value(int);  //Changes and returns value
        mc_int();  //Default constructor
        mc_int(int);//Create from int
        void asBytes(char*); //generate byte array

        mc_int& operator=(int);
        mc_int& operator=(const mc_int&);

        bool endianity;  //true for little
};
```

For conversion and simpler usage, I decided to add `operator=` methods. But I think my implementation of `mc_int& operator=(const mc_int&);` is incorrect.

```
mc_int& mc_int::operator=(const mc_int& other) {
            val = other.value();  
            //    |-------->Error: No instance of overloaded function matches the argument list and object (object has type quelifiers that prevent the match)
}
```

What could this be? I tried to use `other->value()`, but that was wrong too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your member function `value()` is not a `const` function, which means it has the right to modify the members, and cannot be called on `const` objects.  Since I assume you meant it to be read only, change it to `int value() const;`.  Then you can call it on `const` instances of `mc_int`, and it guarantees you don't accidentally change any members.

When it says "Object has type qualifiers blah blah", that means an object has too many `const` or `volatile` qualifiers to access a function.

Also, since you posted a *summary* of an error, I assume you're using visual studio.  Visual Studio shows summaries of errors in the "Error" window.  Go to View->Output to see the full errors in their terrible detail, which should have told you which variable was the problem, and that it couldn't call that function because of it's `const`ness.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
int value();  //Returns value
```

To:

```
int value() const;  //Returns value
```

Answer (score 3):

In this overloaded `operator=`, `other` is a `const` reference. You can only call member functions that are marked `const` on this object. Since the `value()` function just returns `val` and doesn't modify the object, it should be marked as `const`:

```
int value() const;
```

This says that this function won't modify the state of the object and can therefore be called on `const` objects.

Comment: Oh, I don't think I'd ever figure this out, thank you for explaining.